# All custom widgets are not showing in widget area at the same time

Tags: plugins, php, functions, widgets

I have created 3 custom widgets named **Prakash Category Widget**, **Prakash Author Widget** and **Prakash Tag Widget**. Their codes are:

```
<?php
// Begin Prakash Category Widget
/*
Plugin Name: Prakash Category Widget
Description: A Simple Category Widget
Version: 1.0
Author: Prakash Pazhanisamy
Author URI: http://prakashpazhanisamy.wordpress.com
*/

class CategoryWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("text_widget", "Prakash Category Widget",
            array("description" => "A Simple Category Widget"));
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        $cats = get_categories();  // Get categories

        if ($cats) :
        echo '<h2>Categories</h2>';
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($cats as $cat) { 

            // Create a query for the category to determine the number of posts
            $category_id= $cat->term_id;

            $cat_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'cat' => $category_id
            ) );
            $count = $cat_query->found_posts;

            // Print each category with it's count as a list item
            echo "<li>" . $cat->name . " (" . $count . ")</li>";

        }

        wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data 
        echo '</ul>';
        endif;
    }
}
add_action("widgets_init", function () { register_widget("CategoryWidget"); });
// End Prakash Category Widget
?>

<?php
//Begin Prakash Author Widget
/*
Plugin Name: Prakash Author Widget
Description: A Simple Author Widget
Version: 1.0
Author: Prakash Pazhanisamy
Author URI: http://prakashpazhanisamy.wordpress.com
*/

class AuthorWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("text_widget", "Prakash Author Widget",
            array("description" => "A Simple Author Widget"));
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        global $wpdb;

        $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename from $wpdb->users ORDER BY display_name");
        echo "<h2>Authors</h2>";
        foreach($authors as $author) {
            echo "<li>";
            echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
            echo $author->ID;
            echo "\">";
            echo get_avatar($author->ID);
            echo "</a>";
            echo '<div>';
            echo "<a href=\"".get_bloginfo('url')."/?author=";
            echo $author->ID;
            echo "\">";
            the_author_meta('display_name', $author->ID);
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</li>";
        }
    }
}
add_action("widgets_init", function () { register_widget("AuthorWidget"); });
//End Prakash Author Widget
?>

<?php
//Begin Prakash Tag Widget
/*
Plugin Name: Prakash Tag Widget
Description: A Simple Tag Widget
Version: 1.0
Author: Prakash Pazhanisamy
Author URI: http://prakashpazhanisamy.wordpress.com
*/

class TagWidget extends WP_Widget
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct("text_widget", "Prakash Tag Widget",
            array("description" => "A Simple Tag Widget"));
    }

    public function widget($args, $instance) {
        $terms = get_terms('post_tag',array('hide_empty'=>false));
        echo "<h2>Tags</h2>";
        foreach($terms as $t) {
          echo $t->name.' ('.$t->count.')</br>';
        }
    }
}
add_action("widgets_init", function () { register_widget("TagWidget"); });
//End Prakash Tag Widget
?>
```

All the above 3 files are located in **plugins** folder. After activating all the 3 plugins, all custom widgets are not showing in widget area at the same time. It is showing only any one of the widget. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parent::__construct(
    'text_widget', // This should be unique
    'Prakash Author Widget',
    array('description' => 'A Simple Author Widget')
);
```

The first parameter is the Base ID for the widget and should be lowercase and unique. So you have to change `text_widget` to unique strings, e.g. `prakash_author_widget`.